# Obtener TOP 10 ordenado segun contador por catoregorias

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola comunidad de stackoverflow tengo un problema esta es una consulta a mi base de datos de mysql

```
SELECT etiquetas.nombre as tag, 
       segmento.nombre as segmento, 
       tipo_segmento.nombre as subcategoria, 
       SUM(historial_tags_appen.contador) as contador 
FROM `historial_tags_appen` 
INNER JOIN etiquetas on historial_tags_appen.`id_tag` = etiquetas.id_etiqueta 
INNER JOIN tipo_segmento ON tipo_segmento.id_tipo_segmento = etiquetas.id_tipo_segmento 
INNER JOIN etiquetas_segmentos on etiquetas_segmentos.id_etiqueta = etiquetas.id_etiqueta 
INNER JOIN segmento on segmento.idsegmento = etiquetas_segmentos.id_segmento 
WHERE `id_usuario` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `idusuario_app` 
                       FROM `registro_actividad` 
                       WHERE `idpauta` = 175 and `idtipo_actividad` = 2) 
GROUP BY etiquetas_segmentos.id_segmento, etiquetas_segmentos.id_etiqueta 
ORDER BY segmento.idsegmento asc, contador DESC
```

En este fragmento que tengo de la consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT `idusuario_app` 
FROM `registro_actividad` 
WHERE `idpauta` = 175 and `idtipo_actividad` = 2
```

obtengo los id de los registros que me interesa obtener, pueden dar valores de muchos o uno.

El problema es que esta consulta me da todo los valores. Unicamente necesito los 10 primeros por cada `id_segmento` tomando en cuenta su valor de contador, es decir me interesa obtener los 10 que tengan la columna contador con mayor valor para segmento.

Espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Considero que será mas últil que armes un escenario mínimo y verificable, puedes armar un un fiddle donde coloques tus tablas, datos de muestra y así los demás podamos ayudarte de forma mas acertada

Comment: No entiendo mucho, ¿quieres sólo los 10 primeros de la sub-consulta donde tienes el `SELECT DISTINCT` pero ordenados por una columna de otra tabla?

Comment: No, A. Cedano no quiero de la subconsulta, sino de toda la consulta. Lo que tengo actualmente me da todo lo que tenga asocidado a los segmentos o categorias, ordenado por segmento y contador de forma descendente, pero si un segmento me da 100 resultados me los muestra todos, pero solo deseo los primeros 10 de cada categoria o segmento y son muchos segmentos entonces sobrecargaria la base de datos haciendo consultas para cada segmento.

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL?

Comment: la versión 5.6 de mysql, ideal que funcione en versiones antiguas como nuevas. Aunque si en alguna versión reciente hay un método más eficiente lo puedes dejar.

Answer (score 0):

Añade al final `Limit 10` 
Asi limitaras unicamente la consulta a los 10 primeros valores.

Deberia de quedarte asi:

```
SELECT etiquetas.nombre as tag, 
       segmento.nombre as segmento, 
       tipo_segmento.nombre as subcategoria, 
       SUM(historial_tags_appen.contador) as contador 
FROM `historial_tags_appen` 
INNER JOIN etiquetas on historial_tags_appen.`id_tag` = etiquetas.id_etiqueta 
INNER JOIN tipo_segmento ON tipo_segmento.id_tipo_segmento = etiquetas.id_tipo_segmento 
INNER JOIN etiquetas_segmentos on etiquetas_segmentos.id_etiqueta = etiquetas.id_etiqueta 
INNER JOIN segmento on segmento.idsegmento = etiquetas_segmentos.id_segmento 
WHERE `id_usuario` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `idusuario_app` 
                       FROM `registro_actividad` 
                       WHERE `idpauta` = 175 and `idtipo_actividad` = 2) 
GROUP BY etiquetas_segmentos.id_segmento, etiquetas_segmentos.id_etiqueta 
ORDER BY segmento.idsegmento asc, contador DESC LIMIT 10;
```

o como no tengo muy claro cual de las dos es la que te interesa

```
SELECT DISTINCT `idusuario_app` 
FROM `registro_actividad` 
WHERE `idpauta` = 175 and `idtipo_actividad` = 2 LIMIT 10;
```

Te añado enlace de referencia [aqui](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

Comment: No funciona, por que necisito las 10 primeras cada grupo

Comment: de la segunda consulta entonces?

Comment: Tampoco, por que la segunda consulta me da los id que me interesan y pueden ser muchos o pocos.

Comment: Ah, vale, ya entiendo... si, de esta forma no te vale... a ver si se me ocurre algo